# Riemannian Geometry: is there any simple tutorials or lecture notes to understand?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I am working on medical image analysis, and my background is computer science.

I am reading an article and they have applied `Riemannian statistical shape model using differential coordinates`. And they are using `Lie Group`. Which I do not have any idea about these concepts. But I am a fast learner. I need to replicate to this work by coding in C++ and apply some ideas on that. However, I need to learn the concepts thoroughly first.

I am writing here to ask some suggestions from experts in Mathematical Geometry if you know any resources/material/ or lecture notes that have explained these concepts in detail and simple way to understand, please share with me.

Or if there are some codes in any programming language that can help to understand the concepts, please shape.

Your guidance is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't read many books in the subject, but one of my favorites is Sigurdur Helgason's *Differential Geometry, Lie Groups, and Symmetric Spaces.*

Comment: John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds is good, but large.

Comment: Your request seems a little broad and a bit difficult to answer without more information on your precise mathematical background. Are you familiar with the idea of a group? How about a manifold? How much of these concepts do you need to understand. If you want to understand Lie groups and Riemannian manifolds thoroughly, it will probably take you a couple months, perhaps less if you're familiar with groups and manifolds (depending on what thorough means), perhaps longer if you are not.

Comment: Neither is a narrow topic though, and their breadth is part of why thoroughly understanding them will take so long in my estimation. You would probably be better served by getting an intuitive idea of the concepts involved and then narrowly studying *exactly* what you need to know. Ways to do this involve first reading through the wikipedia articles on groups, lie groups, and manifolds, and then googling each new term as it comes up. For narrower terms than lie groups and manifolds, it could be helpful to look up the term in the index of a particular textbook.

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://jakobschwichtenberg.com/naive-introduction-lie-theory/ to grasp some ideas about Lie groups

Comment: The best intro for Riemannian Geometry I know is do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry", more specifically, chapters 0-4. I would not recommend Helgasson's book as the 1st textbook on RG.

Comment: @MoisheKohan there is no softcopy of this book for downloading in SpringerLink, right?

Comment: @S.EB: I do not know, but your library is likely to have a hard copy.